# CSS directory issues

Tags: css, directory

can somebody help me with this directory issues. I have index.php page and have included header and footer.php header contains the `<link href="new.css"/>`, the new.css is located in the main directory. and everytime I try to separate the new.css from the main directory like `css/new.css` it is not working well on other elements but if I try to put it back to the main directory it works fine . can someone tell me why is that happening?

Answer (score 0):

Example:
You have a file: `http://mysite.com/blabla/blabla2/index.php`
Now if you use: `<link href="new.css"/>` - it's same like `<link href="http://mysite.com/blabla/blabla2/new.css"/>`

So you need use this: `<link href="css/new.css"/>`

Comment: nah you didn't got my question i have linked it correctly but its not working

Comment: Please retype your question. Be more specific and use english. You will be more likely to get help.

Comment: that's why I said separate ? isn't that specific enough for you?

Comment: Well, yes I dont uderstand your question. Mean: "You have a file: http://mysite.com/blabla/blabla2/index.php" im talking about path from client (browser) point of view.

Answer (score 0):

try to use `<link href="../css/new.css" />` this might work.